# Size of the TabWidget (Tabspec)

Tags: android, tabwidget

I'm new in android and I want to display one TabWidget whose **Tabspec should have the same size**... it doesn't matter what they have inside... Besides, I have added one HorizontallScrollView because I want to display 8 tabs in my activity, not only 3...

Anybody knows what do I have to add to my xml to have my 8 activities with the same tab size?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"/>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One usually creates a tab like this:

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tag")
                .setIndicator("tab title", icon))
                .setContent(this));
```

This results in the *TabHost* creating the view it chooses to host the *TabSpec*. But there is an overload of *setIndicator*, which takes a *View* as parameter.
So you can create a *View* of fixed width and use this overload of *setIndicator* for your *TabSpecs*.

Comment: Just tested, trying to achieve a 1px-wide tab, it doesn't work. The view is scaled up to finally render the same width than other tabs.